# Find and replace a number with 1 add to it

Tags: script, regex, find-and-replace

I have a large file, which contains something like:

```
no = "33%"
no = "50%"
```

and I have to increase the `33 & 50` by `1` so the result will be

```
no = "34%"
no = "51%"
```

I know this is kind of hard problem, but if you have an idea of how to solve it I will be happy to hear you.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/nppcalc/

Comment: "with Regex, Notepad++ plugin, a dedicated program or even a script" - what is the format of the file? Also your questions seems to be a product recommendation which is off-topic here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible to do this (with some restrictions)
with a purely regex-based approach,
but such a solution would be very awkward and somewhat ugly. 
However, this is not hard in `awk`:

```
awk '
    {
        n=0
        if ($0 ~ /no = "[0-9]+%"/) {
                n = split($0, part, /"/)
                if (n == 3) print part[1] "\"" part[2]+1 "%\"" part[3]
        }
        if (n != 3) print
    }'
```

The (first) `if` statement
tests whether the input line *contains* the characters `no = "`,
followed by one or more digits, followed by `%"`. 
(If you want to match only at the beginning of a line,
add a `^` between the first `/` and the `no`. 
If you want to match only at the end of a line,
add a `$` between the `%"` and the second `/`.) 
We then `split` the line apart at the quotation marks. 
The variable `n` receives the number of parts;
for `no = "33%"`, the count is 3,
and the parts are `no =` , `33%`, and an empty string
(because there is nothing after the second `"`). 
(Note that the quotation marks do not appear in the parts,
because they are the separators.) 
`part[2]+1` will evaluate to `34`,
because `awk` will ignore the `%` after the `33`,
and so the `print` statement puts the pieces of the line back together,
with the number increased by one.

As indicated above,
this script allows other things on the line before and after the number —
but they may not contain quotes. 
For example,

```
The quick brown fox             no = "33%"          What did the bird say?
jumps over the lazy dog.        no = "50%"          Quoth the raven, "Nevermore."
```

will be converted to

```
The quick brown fox             no = "34%"          What did the bird say?
jumps over the lazy dog.        no = "50%"          Quoth the raven, "Nevermore."
```

If a line doesn’t contain `no = "number%"`,
it will not enter the `if` block,
and so it will reach the bottom with `n` equal to 0. 
If it does contain `no = "number%"`,
but has additional quotation marks, then it *will* enter the `if` block,
and `n` will be set equal to the number of quote characters plus one. 
Either way, the `if (n != 3) print`
will cause the input line to be written out, unmodified.

`awk` is a standard program on Unix, Linux, and other Unix-like systems. 
(I have tested this script with the `--posix` option,
so I believe that it doesn’t depend on any GNU extensions.) 
If you don’t have access to a full-blown Unix(-like) machine,
I suggest that you install Cygwin,
or simply find a version of `awk` that runs on whatever your machine is.

Comment: Don't worry, dual boot Ubuntu with Windows. Thanks for the introduction to this amazing utility, I will surely use it regularly. I will figure my way out with more complex scripts.

Answer (score -1):

That's not going to be possible with Regex...

If this is a one-time thing, I would just get Excel involved...
First use Regex to insert a separator (like tab) around the number, so, something like this

```
Find: (.*?)(\d+)(.*)

Replace: \1\t\2\t\3
```

Load this into Excel, increment the number column, save everything as text again, and find/remove the separators.

This is a bit of a silly hack/workaround, but if this is a one time thing, it will be faster than learning to play around with obscure plugins...

Comment: Excel find and replace doesn't support regular expressions. Also he wants to match specific pattern, not just incrementing all numbers.

Comment: Yeh, sorry but that won't work. it is a huge file with lots of data that can't be Imported correctly in Excel